# Generate a list of vacations/leave dates

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem to solve. Here how it goes...

An employee goes on a leave or vacation and this entry is logged in a table with `LEAVE_START_DATE` and `NO_OF_DAYS` (which is number of business days).

A master table contains `DATE`, `IS_WEEK_DAY` (Y/N), `IS_HOLIDAY` (Y/N), and `DAY_OF_WEEK`.

It is required to generate a list of business dates on which the employee was on holiday.

---

**Table `leaves`**

```
LEAVE_START_DATE, NO_OF_DAYS    
2012-05-17, 3
```

---

**Table `days`**

```
DATE, IS_WEEK_DAY, IS_HOLIDAY, DAY_OF_WEEK
2012-05-17, Y, N, 5 
2012-05-18, Y, N, 6 
2012-05-19, N, N, 7 
2012-05-20, N, N, 1
2012-05-21, Y, Y, 2 
2012-05-22, Y, N, 3
```

---

**Expected results**

```
DATE
2012-05-17
2012-05-18
2012-05-22
```

Comment: So how far have you got with this already on your own?

Comment: I tried WITH() recursive approach but no lead there. The solution is required to populate a table while an ETL process on SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must be oversimplifying - Are you asking to select the 3 days from `table days` (which is already populated) that matches the parameters of start date and business days?  If so, the below will work.  Also, you aren't showing what version of `SQL SERVER`, so if it is before 2005 you will have to work around the `parameterized  TOP` with `ROWCOUNT` or whatever you prefer.

```
DECLARE @LeaveStartDate date, @noBusDays int
SET @LeaveStartDate = '2012-05-17'
SET @noBusDays = 3

SELECT TOP (@noBusDays) [DATE] 
FROM [DAYS]
WHERE IS_WEEK_DAY = 'Y' 
AND IS_HOLIDAY = 'N'
AND [DATE] > = @LeaveStartDate
ORDER BY [DATE]
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query will work from SQL server 2008 onwards else if your using 2005 or any version below that you need to change the last top query with a where clause to limit the number of rows

```
 Declare @leaves table
 (Leave_Start_date datetime,No_Of_days int)

 insert into @leaves 
 values ('2012-05-17',3)

 Declare @days table
 ([Date] datetime,
 IS_WEEK_DAY char(1),
 IS_HOLIDAY char(1),
 Day_OF_THE_WEEK int)

 Insert into @days
 values 
 ('2012-05-17','Y','N',5),
 ('2012-05-18','Y','N',6),
 ('2012-05-19','N','N',7),
 ('2012-05-20','N','N',1),
 ('2012-05-21','Y','N',2)

 ;with cte as
 (
  Select [date] from @days where [Date]>=(select Leave_Start_date from @leaves Limit1)
  and is_WEEK_DAY='Y' and IS_HOLIDAY='N'
 )  
 Select top (select no_of_days from @leaves) [date] from cte
```